# Cannot Access Variable Intent on RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> when I declare on other my activity

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

Please someone help me, I want to display image, text, and detail product from `RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>` (First Intent) to My Detail Product Second Intent with intent. But I cannot access variable abc on First Intent when I declare in Second Intent.

Please someone help me.

this is `RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>` or First Intent

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private ImageView image;
    private TextView text;
    private TextView nama;
    private TextView harga;

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        nama= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nama);
        harga = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.harga);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent abc = new Intent(v.getContext(), DetailProduct.class);
                abc.putExtra("abb", my_data.get(getAdapterPosition()).getDetail());
                v.getContext().startActivity(abc);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this is my Detail Product or Second Intent

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_product);
    TextView resulttext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hasiltext);

    String text = abc.getStringExtra("abb"); // i cannot acces variable abc in detailproduct
    resulttext.setText(text);
}
```

Comment: so what error message do you get? Stacktrace / Compiler output?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your post add the information @observer requested in the comment above. That way we can figure out how to help you :) . You should also check out [this article on how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Problem is solved, but when i display image on RecyclerView.Adapter to Detail Product i found the error like this:

Comment: 12-07 06:51:33.603 2159-3754/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for session 889, record source 1999, sample rate 16000, format 0x1, channel mask 0x10, flags 0

Comment: i want to show display image on detailproduct from RecyclerView.Adapter. In the RecyclerView.Adapter i using image from database xampp and i call using Glide library, so i want to display detail image on detailproduct, but my image is url (string). How to fix?                                      
(RecyclerView.Adapter) abc.putExtra("aa", my_data.get(getAdapterPosition()).getGambar()); (DetailProduct)        String cc = getIntent().getStringExtra("aa");
        resultgmb.setImageResource(cc);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in DetailActivity

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_product);
        TextView resulttext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hasiltext);
        if(getTntent()!=null && getIntent().hasExtra("abb")){
        String text = getIntent().getStringExtra("abb"); 
        resulttext.setText(text);
    }
}
```